# Redirect to a new subdomain and set cookie on the redirected subdomain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, subdomain

Express: 4.x

NodeJS: 12.x

On **a.example.com** I have a `GET` listener that redirects to **b.example.com** and sets a cookie on **b.example.com**.

```
app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('name', 'foo', { domain: '.example.com', path: '/', secure: true })
    res.cookie('age', '21', { domain: '.example.com', path: '/', secure: true })
    res.redirect(302, 'https://b.example.com');
})
```

But none of the cookies are set in **b.example.com**. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So I figured out the answer by playing around with the res.cookie options. If anybody comes upon this, here is the right configuration.

Set the httpOnly flag to false if your client javascript application is required to read the cookies.

```
res.cookie('user', 'foo', { path: '/',  domain: '.example.com',  httpOnly:false secure: false  })
res.cookie('age', '21', { path: '/',  domain: '.example.com', httpOnly:false, secure: false  })
res.redirect('https://b.example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for this locally, i.e. on **http**://localhost, you wont see secure cookies.

Comment: This should have been a comment and not an answer. BTW, I am not on localhost.